# android cache huge layout inflation

Tags: android, caching, layout

I'm still somehow new to Android so I probably don't have the necessary layout expertise to make sure I do not create unnecessary view nodes. Currently my main XML layout is huge (around 770 lines) and so it's taking too much to load (around 2 seconds, which makes it feel unresponsive).

I learned about the inflate command which can parse an XML and return a View so i thought I could cache these Views during splash screens using an AssyncTask and just use it in the onCreate() of the main activity.

Might this solve the issue? Is there any other thing I should look into? I'm currently aware of the possibility of a memory leak so I would keep an eye out for that.

Edit: I tried pre-inflating but I dont seem to have achieved a performance increase at all.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null, false);
```

And then in another activity, a while later:

```
setContentView(layout);
```

But still takes the same 2 seconds to open. Am I missing something? Is pre-inflating the way I'm doing it really not supposed to give any improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can "pre-inflate" your views using `LayoutInflater` class. However, I suggest you evaluate your layout performance using [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) tool to pin-point what's going wrong. There are several videos by Romain Guy on how to use this tool. You can also use hints given by Lint (which has replaced the older layoutopt tool) to optimize your layouts. Details about this are [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html).

Comment: I tried pre-inflating but didn't make a difference. Am I stuck with having to refactor the layout itself?